# Insert Custom Object with Task in same DML call?

Tags: apex, class, childrecords

I have a trigger that creates a new custom object record when an Opportunity is Closed Won. I also want to create a series of tasks for this newly created Custom Object record but I don't want to have to insert the custom object and then loop across that list to create and associate my tasks with that custom object record.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? I've tried using the ExternalId text field on the Custom Object, creating the temp record in the loop and then setting my custom object ExtId to the value I used for the temp object but no Dice.

I am trying to set my What value on the Task but can't without an Id.

Here's my code:

```
Group g = [select Id from Group where Name = 'Campaign Queue' and Type = 'Queue' Limit 1];
        List<Campaign__c> cList = new List<Campaign__c>();
        List<Task> tList = new List<Task>();
        RecordType rt = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Campaign' and sObjectType = 'Task'];
        RecordType rt2 = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Campaign Sub-Task' and sObjectType = 'Task'];

        for(Opportunity o : OppList){
            for(Campaign_Line_Item__c cl : o.Campaign_Line_Items__r){
                if(cl.Opportunity__c == o.id){
                    Integer extId = math.round(Math.random()*1000);

                    //Create Sub Tasks First
                    Task t = new Task();
                    t.Subject = 'Campaign Task';
                    t.OwnerId = o.ownerId;
                    t.Status = 'Not Started';
                    t.Priority = 'Normal';
                    t.ActivityDate = system.date.today().addDays(14);
                    t.RecordTypeId = rt2.id;
                    Campaign__c cp = new Campaign__c(External_ID__c = string.valueOf(extId));
                    t.What = cp; // <------Problem Here
                    tList.add(t);

                    Campaign__c cam = new Campaign__c();
                    cam.Name = 'New Campaign '+system.dateTime.Now().
                    cam.Account__c = o.AccountId;
                    cam.Agency__c = o.Agency__c;
                    cam.Partnership_Type__c = o.Partnership_Type__c;
                    cam.Opportunity__c = o.id;
                    cam.OwnerId = g.id;
                    cam.External_ID__c = string.valueOf(ExtId);
                    cam.Stage__c = 'In-Handoff';
                    clist.add(cam);
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: It is inherently impossible to insert parent and child records concurrently, for the exact reason you state. you need the parent's Id.

Comment: Write a trigger on the custom object that when inserted creates the tasks